# R - Weeks of supply

Tags: r, generate-series

I am trying to calculate the number of weeks the inventory on hand will last given the sales projections for a dataset with 10s of million of rows. I have listed the expected output in the last column of the data structure given below. I also attached the implementation of this in Excel.

```
Logic
Weeksofsupply = Number of weeks the current inventory on hand will last.
example - in the attached image (SKU_CD 222, STORE_CD 33), the inventory on hand is 19, the sales values are
WK1 + WK2 = 15, Wk1 + Wk2 + Wk3 = 24, Which is greater than 19, 
So we are picking 2, which the count of Weeks the current inventory will last.
```

## Expected output in the last column

```
Data = structure(list(
SKU_CD = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111,111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222), 
STORE_CD = c(22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33), 
FWK_CD = c(201627, 201628, 201629, 201630, 201631, 201632,201633, 201634, 201635, 201636, 201637, 201638, 201627, 201628, 201629, 201630, 201631, 201632, 201633, 201634, 201635, 201636, 201637, 201638), 
SALES = c(5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 7, 5), 
INVENTORY = c(29, 27, 25, 23, 22, 19, 17, 15, 12, 10, 25, 1, 19, 17, 15, 13, 12,9, 7, 5, 2, 0, 25, 18), 
WeeksofSupply = c("11", "10", "9", "8", "8", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "Inventory More", "Inventory Less", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "Inventory Less", "Inventory Less", "Inventory Less", "Inventory Less", "Inventory Less", "Inventory More", "Inventory More")), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), 
.Names = c("SKU_CD", "STORE_CD", "FWK_CD", "SALES", "INVENTORY", "WeeksofSupply"))
```

[image: Expected output in the last column]

Current Excel Code: (Here the weeks are shown in columns, but it should be rows like shown in the expected output.)

```
=IF(A2<SUM(B2:K2),SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2:K2,,,,COLUMN(B2:K2)-
COLUMN(B2)+1))<=A2))+LOOKUP(0,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2:K2,,,,COLUMN(B2:K2)-
COLUMN(B2)+1))-B2:K2-A2,(A2-(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2:K2,,,,COLUMN(B2:K2)-
COLUMN(B2)+1))-B2:K2))/B2:K2),IF(A2=SUM(B2:K2),COUNT(B2:K2),"Inventory 
exceeds forecast"))
```

[image: Excel Example]

I would appreciate any input to implement this efficiently in R. Many Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your revised data in long format, you can do the following...

```
library(dplyr) #for the grouping functionality

#define a function to calculate weeks Supply from Sales and Inventory
weekSup <- function(sales,inv){
  sales <- unlist(sales)
  inv <- unlist(inv)
  n <- length(sales)
  weeksup <- rep(NA,n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(i==n | inv[i]<sales[i]){
      weeksup[i] <- ifelse(inv[i]>sales[i],NA,inv[i]/sales[i])
    } else {
      weeksup[i] <- approxfun(cumsum(sales[i:n]),1:(n-i+1))(inv[i])
    }
  }
  #Your 'inventory more' is coded as -1 (a number) to avoid whole column being forced to a character vector
  weeksup <- replace(weeksup,is.na(weeksup),-1)
  return(weeksup) #for whole weeks, change this to `return(floor(weeksup))`
}

Data2 <- Data %>% group_by(SKU_CD,STORE_CD) %>% mutate(weekSup=weekSup(SALES,INVENTORY))

head(Data2,20)

   SKU_CD STORE_CD FWK_CD SALES INVENTORY  WeeksofSupply    weekSup
    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>          <chr>      <dbl>
 1    111       22 201627     5        29             11 11.3333333
 2    111       22 201628     2        27             10 10.8333333
 3    111       22 201629     2        25              9  9.8333333
 4    111       22 201630     2        23              8  8.8333333
 5    111       22 201631     1        22              8  8.0000000
 6    111       22 201632     3        19              6  6.6666667
 7    111       22 201633     2        17              5  5.8333333
 8    111       22 201634     2        15              4  4.8333333
 9    111       22 201635     3        12              3  3.6666667
10    111       22 201636     2        10              2  2.8333333
11    111       22 201637     3        25 Inventory More -1.0000000
12    111       22 201638     6         1 Inventory Less  0.1666667
13    222       33 201627     7        19              2  2.4444444
14    222       33 201628     8        17              2  2.0000000
15    222       33 201629     9        15              1  1.6000000
16    222       33 201630    10        13              1  1.2727273
17    222       33 201631    11        12              1  1.0833333
18    222       33 201632    12         9 Inventory Less  0.7500000
19    222       33 201633    13         7 Inventory Less  0.5384615
20    222       33 201634    14         5 Inventory Less  0.3571429
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, using the linear interpolation method `approxfun`...

```
data$WeeksSupply <- sapply(1:nrow(data),function(i)
                     approxfun(cumsum(as.vector(c(data[i,2:11]))),1:10)(data$Inventory[i]))
data$WeeksSupply <- replace(data$WeeksSupply,is.na(data$WeeksSupply),
                            "Inventory Exceeds Forecast")

data
# A tibble: 2 x 12
  Inventory   Wk1   Wk2   Wk3   Wk4   Wk5   Wk6   Wk7   Wk8   Wk9  Wk10                WeeksSupply
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                      <chr>
1       200    20    15    25    40    35    45    30    50    45    55           6.66666666666667
2      2000    20    15    25    40    35    45    30    50    45    55 Inventory Exceeds Forecast
```